# This code dosn't work in my python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm new to coding, and this function is to make all the letters in string or sentence to lowercase and then collect all the letters without spaces. And I can understand the (import string), it worked well in the video of (MIT COURSE) they are using python 2.7......I tried to copy it but...:

```
def toChars(s):  
    import string  
    s = string.lower(s) 
    ans = ''  
    for c in s:    
        if c in string.lowercase:  
            ans = ans + c  
        return ans  

toChars("Test")
```

gives an error:

> AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @DeepSpace Are you sure the braces were not intentional or a problem with code?

Comment: The indentation of `return` is wrong.

Comment: That course sounds _really_ old. `string.lower` and similar functions have been deprecated for ages, long before Python 2.7 was released. You should be using the `str.lower` method, eg `s = s.lower()`.

Comment: **"I tried to copy it but..."** but WHAT? Error? Wrong result? What?

Answer (score 6):

Replace:

```
    s = string.lower(s)
```

with:

```
    s = s.lower()
```

This is the correct way in new python versions.

In addition, change:

```
         if c in string.lowercase:
```

To:

```
         if c.islower():
```

As mentioned in the OP comments you should also fix the indentation of the `return` statement.